# cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object -returning a tuple

Tags: python-3.x, tuples, iterable-unpacking

I don't yet understand why this python code doesn't work; it's part of a little game we are making.
The following function is part of a class:

```
def detectCollision(self,other):
    if(self.x < other.x + other.w and
    self.x + self.w > other.x and
    self.y < other.y + other.h and
    self.y + self.h > other.y):
        return (self,True)
```

Later I call this function from within a loop:

```
for coin in coins[:]:
    
    (player,collided) = bob.detectCollision(coin)    
    if collided:
        coins.remove(coin)
```

But I get an error when I run the code:
"**cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object**".

My understanding from other posts is that this occurs when trying to populate a tuple with only one value or the function doesn't return anything... but my function returns a tuple, so I am at a loss as to why it cannot be unpacked. I also tried removing the brackets around the tuple.

Can anyone please kindly suggest a remedy?

Thank you

Comment: The function returns a tuple only if the condition is true, if it is false it will return `None`

Comment: add `else return (self, False)` at the end of function.

Comment: Ahhh - I see! Yep ok. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As @m.i.cosacak said in the comments you simply need to add another return statement in the form of a tuple to keep its returned values consistent:

```
def detectCollision(self,other):
    if(self.x < other.x + other.w and
    self.x + self.w > other.x and
    self.y < other.y + other.h and
    self.y + self.h > other.y):
        return (self, True)

    return (self, False)
```

so now if the condition is `false` then a tuple will still be returned.